# Prevent stretching / preserveAspectRatio for SVG pattern

Tags: javascript, html, css, vector, svg

I have an svg path that I want to apply a pattern to. However, the pattern seems to be stretching horizontally and I think that I may be applying it incorrectly. Is there a way to make sure that an svg fill pattern maintains its ratio as if it were a background? My code is below and the jsFiddle below that is the similar with a slightly different settings. The pattern I want to apply is 500px by 500px.

```
<svg version="1.1"
 baseProfile="full"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<title>Text Pattern Fill Example</title>
<defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="500" height="500">
        <image xlink:href="img/textures/blogCont/white_wall_hash/white_wall_hash.png" x="0" y="0"
            width="500" height="500" />
    </pattern>
</defs>
<path d="M0 0 C 50 100 80 100 100 0 Z" fill="url(#img1)" />
```

Here is a link to [a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RKLec/)

I am trying to combine [this pattern](http://subtlepatterns.com/white-wall-3/) and the curve effect about 1/3 of the way down [this svg page.](http://tympanus.net/Development/SectionSeparators/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is stretching because you are stretching the whole SVG to the width (but not changing the height).  There really isn't anyway right now to fight that.  If the SVG is not rendered at 1:1 then all the content will be stretched in some way.

Your only option is to scale the SVG in x and y by the same amount.

http://jsfiddle.net/RKLec/1/

Or alternatively, user a workaround such as layering two elements in your HTML.  Eg. Have the image as a background in one `<div>` and put the SVG in another layer and overlap them so that the SVG "masks out" the pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am starting to think that this may not be worth it. The problem with your second suggestion, if I am understanding it correctly, is that the setup won't scale on browser resize... it would just be a fixed image? It seems like there aren't really any good options

Comment: No The SVG curve could scale with the page as long as it didn't have a pattern.  You turn it into the "negative" of what you want and use it as a mask.  Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RKLec/2/

Comment: Thanks BigBadaboom! That seemed to work perfectly. The only thing I have a question with now is how to effectively change the fill in your demo from "green" to another image. For example, the next section has a background-image that is a texture. I was able to set fill="url(#img)" where #img is a pattern as follows. But the proportions seems to stretch.  <defs>
     <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
         <image xlink:href="img/textures/body/low_contrast_linen/low_contrast_linen.png" x="0" y="0" width="256" height="256" />
     </pattern>
 </defs>

Comment: You can't.  That's what I meant by "could scale with the page as long as it didn't have a pattern".  That trick only works as long as only one side has the pattern.